# How can I change Ubuntu server IP Address to web address?

Tags: 14.04, server, dns, webserver

How can I change Ubuntu server IP Address to the web address? For example, the address that I need to access on the browser is 192.168.x.xxx. How can I change to dev.robi.local? Thanks!

The `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost
192.168.0.105 dev.robi.local robi
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

The `resolv.conf` file:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
domain dev.robi.local
search dev.robi.local
```

Comment: Only on your host or on the whole LAN?

Comment: @kos to my whole network

Comment: Either you need setup local DNS server or  add edit /etc/hosts to add this host on each system in you network.

Comment: please note that .local domain is used by the avahi daemon in ubuntu. that is - unless there is something on your network blocking it - you can use <hostname>.local to instead of an ip to name an ubuntu machine from any other ubuntu machine on your local network.

Answer (score 0):

Conventionally name resolution, that is the mapping of IP addresses to host names and vice versa, is done by a DNS (Domain Name System) server.

You probably have an internet router that provides DNS for your local network. There is an offside chance, that your router allows you to add entries to its DNS, but usually customer grade hardware does not offer this. Won't hurt to check, since this would be the easiest way.

As this will probably not be possible, there are multiple ways to go

**Note**: the domain `.local` refers to a system known as **m**(ulticast)**DNS**, aka **zeroconf/bonjour/avahi** - for technical details see the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762). It provides name resolution and service announcement if there is no dedicated DNS server available, although on OS X(bonjour) and Ubuntu (avahi) it is enabled by default.

**Update:** I found the avahi method not immediately viable and setting up a local DNS only makes sense if it can run as the primary DNS for the network.

- Most operating systems maintain a `hosts` file, which contains entries like `IP hostname`. You could manually add an entry (replace x's with the proper IP!)

  ```
    192.168.x.x dev.robi
  ```

to `/etc/hosts` on each client on the LAN. This method is straightforward, but a little impractical, if IPs or hostnames change frequently.

- As noted above, the `avahi-daemon` is running by default on Ubuntu. You can configure the machine to announce itself under multiple names, but there needs to be a mDNS client running on each machine in the LAN, that should resolve the new hostname (on Windows machines, Apples bonjour service is installed with iTunes).
  Give it a try by adding

  ```
    192.168.x.x dev.robi.local
  ```

to `/etc/avahi/hosts` and restart the service with `sudo service avahi-daemon restart`. Now try if the new hostname is resolved e.g. by pinging it from another machine.

**Update:** The described method to use avahi to setup an alias does not work! Avahi will not allow to bind multiple hostnames to the same IP, as it will always try to register a corresponding PTR, which leads to a collision. This is expected and good behavior.
However, there exists an extension [avahi-alias](https://github.com/airtonix/avahi-aliases) which allows to register aliases (CNAME). Unfortunately, those aliases will not be recognized by (at least) Windows clients, but as long as you're only running clients with avahi, this provides a real option.

To install avahi on a Ubuntu system, do

```
    sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon libnss-mdns
```

- Setup a local DNS server. I would recommend `dnsmasq`. It can be installed with `sudo apt-get install dnsmasq`. It comes with a DHCP server which you will want to disable. Its config is stored in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`. To disable DHCP set

  ```
    no-dhcp-interface=eth0
  ```

where `eth0` is the interface connecting to the LAN.
dnsmasq automatically reads `/etc/hosts`, so add your hostname to `hosts` like stated above. <del>Finally add the machine running dnsmasq to the list of DNS servers on each client.</del>

**Update:** You probably have a DNS server running already, e.g on your internet router. The clients will send DNS queries to that server. You cannot simply add a secondary DNS to your clients config, as it will only ever be queried if the primary DNS is unreachable. Unless you're running an always-on machine that can become the primary DNS for the network, there is no way to make this work.

**In Summary:** In a Linux-only environment, where you can run the avahi-daemon on each client, the avahi method actually provides a solution. I tried this myself.

Since you probably cannot turn a machine into an always-on DNS server, installing and configuring `dnsmasq` is *not advised*.

Still, the most straightforward if a little cumbersome method, is to add an entry to the hosts file on each client!

Your recent problem with DNS resolution probably comes from running dnsmasq. I now actually discourage using dnsmasq, since it will not solve your problem. Stop the service `sudo service dnsmasq stop`. Then try `host -v ro.archive.ubuntu.com`. It should resolve using Google's DNS 8.8.8.8 as configured in `resolv.conf`.

Furthermore, if you go with the `hosts` method, do not append the domain `.local`, as it is reserved for mDNS. Instead, just put

```
192.168.0.5 dev.robi
```

in `/etc/hosts`, not `dev.robi.local`.

Comment: It doesn't work @nephente :(

Comment: @user3749583 Which methods do not work?

Comment: that with dnsmasq

Comment: @user3749583 I believe I know what the problem is. First make sure you can reach `dev.robi` from the machine itself, e.g `ping dev.robi`. Then go to another machine and try `host dev.robi robi`. This will query dnsmasq on `robi` instead of the primary DNS. It may be that `host` is not available. You could either install the package `bind9-host`, or if the package `dnsutils` is installed try `dig @robi dev.robi`, which is just another DNS utility. Does the hostname resolve now?

Comment: the response is ,,unknow host dev.robi"

Comment: the directory etc/avahi/hosts doesn't exist...

Comment: @user3749583 the directory is `/etc/avahi/`. It contains a file `hosts`. If not, create it, But make sure you are actually running the `avahi-daemon`: `sudo service avahi-daemon start`

Comment: @user3749583 Related to dnsmasq, please append to your question the contents of `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolv.conf` _from the machine that is running dnsmasq_. Is `dnsmasq` running: `service dnsmasq status` ?

Comment: avahi-daemon: unrecognized service

Comment: dnsmasq is not running @nephente

Comment: @user3749583 Please put the contents of the files into your original question by editing it. Not in the comments! Delete those comments.
Also, it is a little weird that avahi is not available, since it should be standard on Ubuntu. I'll edit my answer in a second...

Comment: when I'm trying to install with sudo-apt get install avahi-daemon, I receive some error that ro.archive.ubuntu.com could not be resolved, and it can fetch the link for download...what should I do?

Comment: @robi10101298 Sorry for not getting back to you yesterday. I've updated my answer. Is there a specific reason, why you're using Google's DNS servers and not e.g your internet router? Also the statement `domain dev.robi.local` in `resolv.conf` is fishy. That is not a domain, but the full hostname.

Comment: I could use my router's IP... that line with domain... it was a sintax that I find on google... I'm new in Ubuntu, so...

Comment: @robi10101298 If you want to use Google's DNS thats perfectly fine. But remove the `domain` and `search` statement from `resolv.conf`. You do not have a domain. `.local` will be automatically used by avahi. I would try the avahi-aliases method, it tried it in my home network and it worked.